# jfreechart: set Item Shape position

Tags: jfreechart

I use `setSeriesShape(seriesindex, new Rectangle(5,5))` to draw itemshapes.
But somehow they end up not being centered.
Is there a method to set position?

[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1144075/Bildschirmfoto%202010-08-05%20um%2011.36.45.JPG](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1144075/Bildschirmfoto%202010-08-05%20um%2011.36.45.JPG)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `new Rectangle(-2, -2, 5, 5)`.